# How to XML-encode a string in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

Question: I can create a XML-encoded string in Postgres like this:

```
SELECT xmlelement(name name, 'AT&T', null )
```

now I want to get the xml encoded value, that is to say `AT&amp;T`.

But if I do:

```
SELECT unnest(xpath('/name/text()', xmlelement(name name, 'AT&T', null )))
```

then I get `AT&T`, not `AT&amp;T`.

How can I get the XML-encoded value?

Furthermore, isn't it possible to supply an empty name to xmlelement, and just cast to varchar?

Comment: I get `AT&amp;T` in 9.2. Where are you outputting that value?

Comment: SELECT version(); --> "PostgreSQL 9.0.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1500, 32-bit" in pgAdmin3 Version 1.12.3 (Apr. 15 2011 REL-1_12_3)

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to use a simple function.

```
create or replace function xml_escape(s text) returns text as
$$
  select replace(replace(replace(s, '&', '&amp;'), '>', '&gt;'), '<', '&lt;');
$$
language sql immutable strict;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing to an HTML client then you will have to HTML escape that for it to show the raw HTML.

As I  see you are mainly a C# developer then the static method `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()` will do it.

Comment: @Quandary I don't understand your comment.